# getting two grid colums right next to each other

Tags: css

I'm trying to get two grid columns to be next to each other, right now there is only one column and they're right below each other.

css

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:989px) {
  main section{
    display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; 
  gap: 0px 0px; 

  }
```

[image: four images in a grid column where they're 2 by 2 right next to each other]

I received an answer that pointed me in the right direction and made me realize im not targeting the right elements in my css. So im going to repost this with my html to try and get a clearer understanding of why im not targeting the right elements.

```
 <main>
  <section class="winter">
  <div class="outside-border">
    <div class="section-heading">
      <h2>Winter</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="inside-border">
      <div class="winter-image">
        <a href="winter.html">
          <img src="assets/images/winter.jpg" alt="Winter Image">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="section-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit       dolore enim sequi dignissimos vel fugit
          reiciendis minus voluptatem nostrum, at repellat odio libero cum eveniet officiis, cumque veritatis, qui
          eaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </section>

  <section class="spring">
    <div class="outside-border">
      <div class="section-heading">
        <h2>Winter</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="inside-border">
        <div class="winter-image">
          <a href="winter.html">
            <img src="assets/images/winter.jpg" alt="Winter Image">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="section-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit dolore enim sequi dignissimos vel fugit
            reiciendis minus voluptatem nostrum, at repellat odio libero cum eveniet officiis, cumque veritatis, qui
            eaque.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  
  </section>

  <section class="summer">
    <div class="section-heading">
      <h2>Summer</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="section-image">
        <a href="summer.html">
          <img src="assets/images/summer.jpg" alt="Summer Image">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="section-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit dolore enim sequi dignissimos vel fugit
          reiciendis minus voluptatem nostrum, at repellat odio libero cum eveniet officiis, cumque veritatis, qui
          eaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="autumn">
    <div class="section-heading">
      <h2>Autumn</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="section-image">
        <a href="autumn.html">
          <img src="assets/images/autumn.jpg" alt="Autumn Image">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="section-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit dolore enim sequi dignissimos vel fugit
          reiciendis minus voluptatem nostrum, at repellat odio libero cum eveniet officiis, cumque veritatis, qui
          eaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

This is my main html and im trying to select an element so that each section ends up like the picture. With the winter and spring section next to each other and then the summer and fall section underneath, the other two.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] and take the [tour] to best understand how to use and benefit from the site. The inclusion of your CSS is helpful, but without your HTML I am afraid this falls short of a [mcve], which is critical in providing the community with enough context to assist you.  Please include enough code to recreate the issue.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Your screen shot shows a grid with two rows and two columns. Your code specifies a grid with two rows and two columns. Or are you trying to prevent the space between the cards? Can you edit your question to include a working snippet? Or post a link to the page you're working on ...

Comment: For your example, just change the css selector from `main section` to `main` and it will work.

Comment: oh man that is what exactly was the issue, i had main section when i should have just had main. Thank you for your help i really appreciate you being so patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work. If your html is correct and if you test it between 768px and 989px.

```css
main section{
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; 
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; 
    gap: 0px 0px; 
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 150px;background-color: red;"></div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 150px;background-color: blue;"></div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 150px;background-color: green;"></div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 150px;background-color: yellow;"></div>
  </section>
</main>
```

**UPDATE**

For your structure just change css selector from `main section` to `main`